# Common method of calculating zero places of quadratic and linear function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Very basic stuff from school we know that we can calculate zero places of quadratic function which has form $ax^2 + bx + c$ and we assume that $a \neq 0$, now
what if $a=0$? Why can't we use delta to calculate zero places of linear function? I know it's very easy to calculate zero place of linear function, but i'm quite interested in such stuff. Thanks for any response.

EDIT : 
Right, to make my question more understandable: From where such formula of roots of quadratic function come from? And as interesting as possible, elaborate this topic! i'll be greatly grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, using the quadratic formula to find the "zeros" (roots) of a quadratic: solving for $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, is not defined for $a = 0$, since the quadratic formula $$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$ is undefined when $a = 0$: we cannot be divided by $2a = 2\cdot 0 = 0$. And furthermore, when $a = 0$, the equation is no longer quadratic; it defines a line.

So, when $a$ in $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, and $a = 0$, we have $bx + c = 0$, and provided $b$ is not zero, then the single zero (solution for $x$) is given by $$bx = -c \implies x = -\dfrac cb, \quad b\neq 0.$$

---

EDIT: You might want to read about the [**Quadratic Equation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) in Wikipedia. The entry covers the history behind the formula, explains how to derive the formula and why it gives the roots (zeros) of a quadratic, lists variations on/alternatives to the formula, and alternative methods for solving such equations, and ways in which it can be used/adapted for higher dimensional equations.

See also [Quadratic formula](http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/quadraticeq/quadraformula/quadraformula.html) @ sosmath.com

Comment: Certainly deserves a thumbs up! +1

Comment: That's really sweet, @Babak!

Answer (score 2):

Let us fix $b$ and $c$, with $b\gt 0$. Think of $a$ as **variable**.

You are undoubtedly familiar with the fact that if $a\ne 0$, then the roots of the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c=0$ are given by 
$$x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$
The above formula is troublesome at $a=0$, for obvious reasons!

We sidestep some unpleasantries by looking only at the root $\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. We will examine the behaviour of this root as $a$ **approaches** $0$.

First note that if $a\ne 0$, then 
$$x=\frac{-b+ \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{-b+ \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\cdot \frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}.$$
But $\left(-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\right)\left(b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\right)=-4ac$, so we obtain 
$$x=\frac{-4ac}{(2a)\left(b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\right)}=\frac{-2c}{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}.$$
Now we can safely let $a$ approach $0$. As $a$ approaches $0$, $b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ approaches $2b$. It follows that the root of the quadratic approaches $\frac{-2c}{2b}$, which is the right answer for the root of the linear equation $bx+c=0$.

**Remark:** Much too elaborate to be an answer to your question! But I thought it would be interesting to show how the solution of the linear equation can be viewed as a limit of the standard solution of the quadratic.

Comment: For those who might be interested, this used to be a standard topic in quadratic equations (especially in the 1800s), at least in texts written in English. See the [google-books search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=quadratic+%22infinite+root%22) for the simultaneous search of the word "quadratic" and the phrase "infinite root".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "use delta," but the zero of $bx+c$ is given by $x=-\frac{c}{b}$, which you can check by plugging in.

Comment: ah, okay sorry. 
delta is given by $delta = b^2 - 4ac$ 
and zero places of quadratic function is 
$x1=\frac{-b+\sqrt(delta)}{2a}$ and

$x2=\frac{-b-\sqrt(delta)}{2a}$.